# Change Android Button enable and disable style in framework

Tags: android

I am working on android frameworks. I need to modify the default enabled and disabled text colour of the `Button` to different colours.
can anyone help he where the default style of `Button` exists

Comment: as per Your question You want to do custom style on button ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Android Framework source code at [grepcode](http://grepcode.com). I think below link can help you.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/Button.java/

Answer (score 0):

use a color state list for your view.
read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html